# Check if each letter in ArrayList<String> is a certain character?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, character, stringbuilder

Firstly, I'm SUPER new to stackoverflow (so excuse my ugly formatting), and have only a few years of programming experience (about 6 programming classes total)

I'm working on a hangman project. I've elected to use a `StringBuilder` for some of it. For example, I want to check what index or indices the char `chosenLetter = 'C'` is in the `StringBuilder chosenWord = new StringBuilder("Ceramics");`

Ideally, I would have a for loop to go through the `StringBuilder` word "Ceramics" and tell me the indices `0` and `7`. I absolutely cannot figure it out. I've tried using the `indexOf()` function, but for some reason if I do

```
for (int i = 0; i < chosenWord.length(); i++) {
     if (chosenWord.indexOf(chosenLetter, i) != -1) {
        System.out.println("This should be a match at index " + i);
    }
}
```

It would print out for example:

> This should be a match at index 0
>
> This should be a match at index 1
>
> This should be a match at index 2
>
> This should be a match at index 3
>
> This should be a match at index 4
>
> This should be a match at index 5
>
> This should be a match at index 6
>
> This should be a match at index 7
>
> This should be a match at index 8

Instead of

> This should be a match at index 0
>
> This should be a match at index 7

Any ideas how to go about doing this? Thanks.

And again, sorry for the ugly format. If there's any questions on clarification I would be glad to try to clarify!

Comment: So, maybe [`StringBuilder#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) is out of the question?

Comment: You simply do not understand what `chosenWord.indexOf(chosenLetter, i)` does.

Comment: why don't you just do StringBuilder.toString().equals()? It seems like behind the scenes it would be pretty similar and probably less error-prone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out

```
 for (int i = 0; i < chosenWord.length(); i++) {
    if (chosenWord.charAt(i) == chosenLetter) {
    System.out.println("This should be a match at index " + i);
    }
    }
```

This will print your desired out put

Comment: i guess you need to work out to get the case insensitive part. as it will just match the "c" not "C" or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringBuilder#indexOf(String, int)`, but you need to be sure to increment the `index` position after each successful match, otherwise you will end up in a infinite loop...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("ceramics");
int index = 0;
while ((index = sb.indexOf("c", index)) >= 0) {
    System.out.println(index);
    index++;
}
```

Should also beware, that this is a case sensitive search, as you can see, I've made the text all lower case so I can catch positions `0` AND `6`

The basic issue with your first attempt is that you are actually ignoring the result of `indexOf`

```
if (chosenWord.indexOf(chosenLetter, i) != -1) {
    System.out.println("This should be a match at index " + i);
```

But then print `i`, so on each iteration, you are getting a result of either `0` or `6`, so hence the reason it prints results for `0` - `6`

So...

```
i = 0; chosenWord.indexOf(chosenLetter, i) == 6, print 0
i = 1; chosenWord.indexOf(chosenLetter, i) == 6, print 1
i = 2; chosenWord.indexOf(chosenLetter, i) == 6, print 2
i = 3; chosenWord.indexOf(chosenLetter, i) == 6, print 3
i = 4; chosenWord.indexOf(chosenLetter, i) == 6, print 4
i = 5; chosenWord.indexOf(chosenLetter, i) == 6, print 5
i = 6; chosenWord.indexOf(chosenLetter, i) == 6, print 6
i = 7; chosenWord.indexOf(chosenLetter, i) == -1, ignored
```

You actually don't need the outter loop, you just need to keep looping until `indexOf` is `< 0`, as demonstrated above...

Comment: If you plz explain the issue too, I would be so happy to vote u up

Comment: @KickButtowski I was hoping to ignore it, check update, see if that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are seeing that output is because [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) will return 0 for `i` = `0` and `6` for `i` = `1` to `7`.  In all those cases, the return is different from `-1`, which satisfies the `if` statement.  Consider using [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#charAt(int)), in the same way suggested by @ppuskar.